# Double-slit experiment and hidden variables

Tags: quantum-mechanics, double-slit-experiment, bells-inequality

I wonder if double-slit experiment can be considered a proof of non-existence of local hidden variables in quantum mechanics?

Consider this: probability $P(A \: \textrm{or} \: B)$ that either one of two events A and B or both happen is
$$
P(A \: \textrm{or} \: B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \: \textrm{and} \: B) 
$$
Additional term here accounts for probability of two events being non-exclusive (happening at the same time), in which case we would have counted them twice.

In double-slit experiment, we can consider $A$ and $B$ to be events of going through one of the slits. According to QM the interference of amplitudes $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ gives
$$
P(A \: \textrm{or} \: B) = |\mathcal{A} + \mathcal{B}|^2 = P(A) + P(B) + 2\Re \left(\mathcal{A}^*\mathcal{B} \right)
$$
The interference term $2\Re \left(\mathcal{A}^*\mathcal{B} \right)$ can be both positive and negative, depending on the point on the screen. But in the first equation additional term can only be negative. Thus, it would seem, we can't describe quantum interference as a result of combining certain isolated events.

I'm sure it's not that simple, but can't really see what's I'm missing in this reasoning.

Comment: Are you assuming that the double slit experiment measures which slit the particle goes through? The whole point of the double slit experiment is that you *don't* know which slit the particle went through.

Comment: @BioPhysicist No, I know it doesn't measure which slit the particle goes through. What I mean is, if there _were_ some hidden variables that predict which slit a particle goes through (maybe in a very complicated way), the probabilities would still obey the first equation. But since they don't, we can deduce that no such variable exist.

Comment: @BioPhysicist see also my comments on Emilio Pisanty's answer below

Comment: I don’t think the bells-inequality tag is applicable here.

Comment: @SuperfastJellyfish I'd tag it "hidden variables" but there isn't one, so I chose the closest one found

Comment: I'm with Xava. I was trying to explain this to a friend and it suddenly occurred to me that I don't understand why double slit doesn't already prove there's no hidden variable. The atom had an equal probability of going thru either slit so it went thru both slits at the same time. There was no hidden variable that determined it should go thru the left or the right slit.

Answer (score 1):

> Thus, it would seem, we can't describe quantum interference as a result of combining certain isolated events.

Yes, this is correct. However, nothing in your argument has any real bearing on the existence of hidden variables, or indeed on the double-slit experiment.

Comment: I mean... if there were any hidden variables that predict which of the slits a particle would actually go through... then the probabilities would obey the first equation, right?

Comment: I'm probably confusing non-existence of trajectories with hidden variables. But now that I think of it, I don't see what the difference is between the two concepts.